# Multiple FOR var loops that read from config Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, var

I'm setting up my code and having an issue.. 
This code is just an example what i'm trying to do.
SO basically config.Te[i].ref should read all the ref in Te.. but it only reads the first row instead of all rows in Te...

regards

```
for (var i in config.acc,config.Te,config.Hu,config.Ve) 

                console.log(config.Te[i].ref)
          {}
```

when i change the log output to config.acc[i].ref or other, it also reads the first row only of that specific config.

but when i change it to for (var i in config.acc) it reads all the ref...

so i think i formatted the code wrong, and i dont know how to fix it.
the error must be in seperating the configs.
i just want to call them seperatly 1 by 1.

```
"acc":
            [
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 },
            {"type":"PIR",      "ref":0 }
            ],
```

Comment: `for (var i in config.acc,config.Te,config.Hu,config.Ve)` is equivalent to `for (var key in config.Ve)` [MDN Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and I assume that `config.Ve` has only 1 row.

Comment: @Thomas  no they all have many rows.. thats why im asking how to solve this issue... like i want to call the refs by  console.log(config.Te[i].ref) and  so on

Comment: *"i want to call the refs by console.log(config.Te[i].ref) and so on"* how about `for (var i in config.Te) console.log(config.Te[i].ref);`

Comment: @Thomas thank you, i already know that. like the question above is how can i do that with the rest, as the above code gives me only 1 row instead of all of them per array... and indeed if i use for (var i in config.Te) this wil give me the info i needed for this one only.. how about the rest? i just want  to merge them into one code. so that i can call this, console.log(config.acc[i].ref) console.log(config.hu[i].ref) console.log(config.ve[i].ref).

Comment: Finally, I think I get what you meant with that construct `for(var i=0, length=Math.max(config.acc.length,config.Te.length,config.Hu.length,config.Ve.length); i<length; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: @Thomas probably worth an answer.

Comment: @Thomas thats works, but only it gives me a new error when i put this code in it : if(myData.ref == config.acc[i].ref) { MY ACTION}   gettiong this error after it : Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined. the error code is from config.acc[i].ref

Comment: It seems that `acc` is not as long as one of the other lists; or maybe it has gaps, I don't know your data. You can not blindly access the properties of a value in any of the lists, because the value/index may not exist in that particular list. That's the price for this approach you want to use; you have to do null-checks.

Comment: @Thomas `for(var i=0, length=Math.max(config.acc.length,config.Te.length,config.Hu.length,config.Ve.length); i<length; ++i) {console.log(config.acc[i].ref)}` shows the value's normal.. but why it doesnt if i use `for(var i=0, length=Math.max(config.acc.length,config.Te.length,config.Hu.length,config.Ve.length); i<length; ++i) {if(myData.ref == config.acc[i].ref) { console.log(config.acc[i].ref)}}`

Comment: @Thomas i got it working, but it only reads 5 rows max... how to increase it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your main objects in array and then use nested for loop.

```
const arr = [config.acc,config.Te,config.Hu,config.Ve]
for(let elm of arr){
   for(let i in elm){
      console.log(elm[i].ref)
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your very quick reply, this wil result when i make an event that everything triggers. i just want to see like if i use: console.log(config.Te[i].ref) that it only list the ref from Te and so on. and not all the other ones.. is that possible ?

Comment: Can i call the log seperatly from the configs ? like if i want only to see the info from config.Hu how do i do that ?  console.log(elm[i].ref) this gives me all of them.